# One-time pad XOR question

Tags: one-time-pad, xor

For a one-time pad to be truly secure, do I need to use [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher)? In other words, is a numerical OTP as secure as a XORed one?

I'm new to cryptography, so this might not even make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do [not need to use XOR](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/33067/29554) as the combining operation. You can use [modular addition](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/modular-addition-and-subtraction) as the encryption function and modular subtraction as the decryption function and it will remain information theoretically secure.

XOR is typically used because it is convenient -- it is its own inverse (an "involution"), and it is smaller/simpler to implement in hardware than adders and multipliers.